# owl carousel in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, carousel

I'm trying to get owl carousel working with in my rails app.  I've got this block of code which sets up the carousel...

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
<% @photo.each do | p| %>
<div> <%= cl_image_tag(p.uri) %> </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

but not sure what to do with this ?  is it some jquery that's needed to start the carousel?

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

I'm not sure how to get it going.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

It does, and you put options in there :
.
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html.

Comment: ok, how do I add that jquery to my rails app?  still confused.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby on rails.
What version of owl carousel do you use? 
Have you tried this specific plugin for ruby : https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails ?

Comment: yes , i'm using carousel-rails.  

I tried adding this script to my page...

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        item: 2
    });
});

</script>

Comment: The code you posted seems fine. I think you didn't load something. First do a console.log('test') in the $(document).ready. If 'test' isn't displayed it means that you didn't load Jquery properly.

Else I think you didn't load some file, verify that you did as told in 1.Getting Started on the owlcarousel-rails github

Comment: yes, jquery is loaded correctly.  I can't even get the demo owl carousel working.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();` to application.js

If you are using Turbolinks, make sure you wrap around the JS code with the Turbolinks on load. It will looks like this:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
   $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

You can then put the settings for your owlCarousel:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
   $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
      // Your settings goes here
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true
});
```